# Excel/Excel VBA cut and copy resets cell name

Tags: excel, vba

The situation is simple, if I name cell `A1` to be `MY_CELL` and then **CUT AND PASTE** from cell `A2` to cell `MY_CELL`, then `MY_CELL` will lose that name and be named `A1` again.

However, this does not happen when I **COPY AND PASTE** from `A2` to `MY_CELL`.

How can I prevent Excel from resetting cell names on **CUT AND PASTE**?

Comment: I know you have tagged it as `vba-Excel` so are you open for a vba code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Hi, I am definitely open to any code fixes you can suggest. Thanks

Comment: @pnuts, Hi, I don't think the users would be very happy if they had to do that every time just to cut and paste some rows..thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: 2 mins.. posting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic**: Trap the changes to Cell `A1` using the `Worksheet_Change` event and recreate the name if it is lost.

**Code**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DoesRngNameExists As Boolean
    Dim sName As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '~~> You named range
    sName = "MY_CELL"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check if the Range exists
        On Error Resume Next
        DoesRngNameExists = Len(Names(sName).Name) <> 0
        On Error GoTo 0

        '~~> If not then recreate it
        If DoesRngNameExists = False Then _
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1"
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Note**: The codes in the Sheet code area of the relevant sheet. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Note: If your sheet name is not `Sheet1` then you will have to change it here as well `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1"` Alternatively you can use this code instead. `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersToR1C1:="=" & Activesheet.Name & "!R1C1"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could I expand this answer to include multiple named cells in the target range if a user were to cut and paste an entire row?

Comment: increase the scope here `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Hi Siddharth. How can I change the `RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1"` portion to a `row` and `range` obtained from the `Range.Row` and `Range.Column` properties?

Comment: `R1` means `Row 1` and `C1` means `Column 1` so `R1C1` together means `Row 1 Column 1` which is nothing but Cell `A1` The above code can also be written as `RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R" & Rowno & "C" & ColNo` Where `Rowno` and `ColNo` are row number and Col number which for example can be `Range.Row` and `Range.Column`

Comment: Hi Siddharth Rout, I am getting an error on `DoesRngNameExists = Len(Names(sName).Name) <> 0` my `sName` in this case is `sName = "STATUS_FIELDS"`. Would you have any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you remove the line "On Error Resume Next" before that line as shown above?

Comment: Yes I did when I was testing, but I found out that if I use `ThisWorkbook.Names(...)` then it is ok.

Comment: You need to put it back :) beacuse if the name doesn't exist then you will get an error which we want to ignore.

Comment: I understand and I have put it back. However, my `DoesRngNameExists` returns `True` even when the range name is not in `Names`.

Comment: I have put it back and removed `This.Workbook.Names(...)` and only have it as `Names(...)` and now it returns `False` correctly. Could you please explain this? I am so confused....

Comment: Is your query sorted or you are still stuck?

Comment: Rout, my question has been resolved with your solution. Thanks! But could you please explain why `DoesRngNameExists` always returns `True` with `ThisWorkbook.Names(...)` but returns `False` properly when I change to `Names(...)`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28053/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-czchlong)

Comment: i would love to continue in chat but my company restricted that due to it being a chat site...i will leave you a message in chat when I am home?